# Reducing number of attributes stored in table

Tags: database, database-design

I have a problem in creating a table for a database. I want to record many status for each farmer for example farmer will perform many procedures in paddy farming and have about 26 procedures from cultivation until harvesting.

So, each farmer must follow a schedule for each procedure according to dates fixed by Agriculture assistant. My problem is how can I record this procedure status to record whether the farmer is following the schedule or not? For now, I use the 26 procedures as the attributes for the activity table so in the activity table I have attributes

```
farmerID, status1 (for activity 1 eg: Cultivation) , 
status2 (for activity 2 eg: fertilization), 
status 3
```

and so on until status 26...so is this the correct way? My lecturer says it is incorrect because so many attributes are there. Can you help me out from this problem? I can't think about this any more.

Answer (score 3):

Not a good way of handling it, especially since it's not immediately scalable without adding new fields (and having your code map those new fields). I'd do something like this:

tbl_farmer
- farmerId

tbl_status
- statusId
- name (i.e. Cultivation, etc.)

tbl_activity
- farmerId
- statusId

And each time a farmer performs a status update, you place the entry inside tbl_activity. Basically tbl_activity is a reference table

Comment: can u give me an example...so in table activity i'll have the same ID of farmers many time right? about 26 time because each farmer will perform 26 activities....

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to give each activity (procedure) an id and instead of many columns only have three.

```
farmer_id
activity_id
status
```

Assuming that your activities are stored in a separate table.

Comment: So sorry i cant imagine how this table looks like...i have draft it but still cant understand...did i need to repeat the farmers ID 26 times? because each farmers will perform 26 activities...

Comment: Yes, you will need 26 rows for each farmer id, but adding a new activity or farmer (especially an activity) won't be as difficult in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

[image]